# IIS reverse proxy

Tags: iis, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a Windows 8 box as a "reverse proxy" web server using IIS.

My goal is as simple as it gets. I do not need subdomains to go to different servers, but rather to redirect all port-443 (SSL) traffic to localhost:2080. Basic auth should be performed by IIS.

I had this config working fine with apache, but I need to migrate to IIS. I have been trying to get IIS to do that for a week now, without any success. I feel depressed and worthless.

Would a good soul out there be willing to explain me, in a few steps, how the above can be accomplished? Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do i with the modules URL Rewriting and Application Request Routing.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

If you only have one backend server route traffic straight to it and just use URL rewriting to port redirect traffic locally.

edit: or use HTTP redirection which might be the best alternative.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(v=ws.10).aspx

http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/11/how-to-redirect-sites-to-https-in-iis-7-5/

Comment: +1. Perfect. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

ISA/TMG is a good option on Windows, [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org) are also available - easier to do.

Comment: thank you, but could you elaborate on why you advise to stay away from IIS?

Comment: -1. I downvote for ONE reason: TMG is end of life. It does not even work on a CURRENT server (2012). No more updates coming. Same here - stuck in it, working on replacing it. Sorry, this is a dead end.

Comment: aag, IIS is web server, of course, you can use it as reverse proxy like apache+mod_proxy, but Microsoft has another product for that and it's functionality is reverse proxy. If you are migrating from Linux - you should be familiar with squid or varnish already, so, for you it could be easier to do this way - much better than nothing. For IIS you need to write something, for other products (incl. TMG/UAG) - no. TomTom, really? I mean, REALLY? TMG mainstream support will cease after 14 April 2015 and extended support will end on 14 April 2020. Forefront Unified Access Gateway is also available.